# Construct a Simple grammar that generates L :

Tags: context-free-grammar

```
L ={ a^n b^n c^m | n,m>0}
```

Here is a question, but I can't generate any grammar that actually matches simple grammer limitations rules.
Is there a way that can tell if a simple grammar exist for a language?

Comment: A context-free grammar G = (V, T, S, P) is said to be a simple grammar or s-grammar if all its productions are of the form A → ax, where A ∈ V, a ∈ T, x ∈ V*, and any pair (A, a) occurs at most once in P.

Comment: Please give an example how to express `L ={ c^m | m>0}` by means of "simple grammar".  It seems to be impossible without introducing new terminal "end of string".

Comment: L ={ c^m | m>0} is hard for me to convert but here's an example:  L={a^n b^n , n>0}
 S → aB
 and B → aBD
and B → b
and D → b

Comment: I think you need to clarify (by editing your question) what exactly you mean by "simple grammar". I think you mean something like Griebach Normal Form (perhaps with some additional restrictions) but it is not at all clear.

Comment: yes it is very similar to Griebach Normal Form but every pair(V,T) needs to be unique

Answer (score 0):

```
S -> aHcT
H -> aHb
H -> b
T -> cT
T -> empty string
```

Comment: in simple grammar we have this rule that: A -> aX    (A,a) must be unique if exist. in your grammer T and H are not unique

Comment: there can't be a empty string in transitions they must have a terminal or they must have first one terminal then a variable or set of variables

Answer (score 0):

I like this:

```
S->TC
T->aUb
C->cD
U->T|null
D->C|null
```

**UPDATE**

```
    S->TC
    T->U
    C->D
    U->aTb|ab
    D->cC|c
```

Comment: simple grammer needs to be in this form: A ->aX A is a variable, X can be a set of variables, a is a Terminal A -> a a is a Terminal and (A,a) is unique in productions if exists.
in your answer there must be a terminal before every variable that your using, and we don't have a null transition in simple grammer.